Adjust GameMaker tags to be one word, reflect legacy switch
Our tags for Gamemaker are game-maker and game-maker-studio-2.
This tool hasn't been called "Game Maker" since 2012 when its name changed. (thanks @liggiorgio!)
Should we change these tags to gamemaker and gamemaker-studio-2?
EDIT: I also have parts of the below part wrong. See @liggiorgio's answer for a good plan of action.
Also, the big change in it from "legacy" to what we have now happened with 2.3. Maybe we need new tags to indicate this bifurcation?

Awww, but i know why you did it. :)

FWIW, "game-maker" is much easier to read than "gamemaker" :P

I write an answer just for the sake of having a checkmark that agrees with the whole post (if this gets accepted).

It seems there are two issues at hand here

do we change game-maker to gamemaker and game-maker-studio-2 to gamemaker-studio-2?
do we do something about newer versions that make older versions obsolete?

So, 1. yes, like the other answer says, it makes sense to me to rename those tags.
And for 2., it seems there is yet another naming scheme from YoYo game as stated on Wikipedia:

In April 2022, YoYo Games dropped the GameMaker Studio 2 name in order to match its new version numbering scheme, changing it to simply GameMaker.

So it makes it even more complicated to know what's going on in which version because gamemaker would cover two very different versions. I have opinions on this but it does not matter in the scope of this answer. For the record, a previous discussion suggested that new versions for tags should be created only " if there is a significant functional difference between the versions of the thing in question". Since there seems to be a lot of things to consider for this, I suggest a new Meta question is created just to discus this.

In conclusion, upvoting this answer means we agree to rename the tags as suggested in the Question post, and nothing more (for now, w.r.t. the tags/main site).

Related: Tag synonyms and "version specific" synonyms

I went ahead and "merged" (renamed) the tags [tag:game-maker] to [tag:gamemaker], and [tag:game-maker-studio-2] to [tag:gamemaker-studio-2], and [tag:game-maker-dnd] to [tag:gamemaker-dnd]. I have also created synonyms for the old ones to point toward the new ones.


This tool has never been called "Game Maker", it was always one word.

I see that "Game Maker" was the legacy name until 2011 when GM v8.1 came out. Funnily, the first question ever with a game-maker tag dates back right to April 2011. I guess the misnaming was due to the transition happening back then.

Should we change these tags to "gamemaker" and "gamemaker-studio-2"?

Yes, I'm in for it. We may also set some tag synonyms for people still calling it differently.

Also, the big change in it from "legacy" to what we have now happened with 2.3.

AFAIK YoYo Games only changed their business model with GMS v2.3, but the core GMS experience seems the same as v2.x. I would instead argue that any version up to GMS v1.99 is deprecated, and "legacy" may apply to either GMx vs. GMSx or obsolete vs. currently supported.

Ok; so my impression was from seeing code from 2.3 with warnings about maybe not working prior, thanks for all this information! :)

I guess those warnings are likely due to new features added, rather than a brand-new codebase and product.

To be pedantic, " the first question ever with a game-maker tag", the tag was added to that question in 2021 using an edit. The earlier question I found with a tag was this one in October 2011.

I would upvote this for the "first part" about renaming the tags, but I'm not super clear on what the rest of the answer implies. Do you think we need new tags? Or do you think we need to rename older tags to something-something-legacy? I've written an answer to this question, and I think this could/should have its own discussion!

@Vaillancourt Thanks for being pedantic, I definitely overlooked that edit
